# texworks with texlive setup for the bibiliography

Tags: natbib, texworks

I have a new setup of texworks and texlive on my windows 10 laptop. When I run pdflatex all the inline citation become [?] and no bibiliography is generated. If I run the same tex and bib file in the office computer, it works normally. Hence I know that it is not the issue with tex or bib files. Can anyone please help me what kind of configuration checks/changes i need to do to resolve this issue.

## here is the bibliography related message in the log file

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dirac1953888' on page 2 undefined on input li
ne 106.

No file elsarticle-template.bbl.

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 112.

## [2]

Comment: What does the .blg-file say?

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer I couldn't locate .blg file.

Comment: If it isn't there you didn't run bibtex. But check all files again --windows sometimes hide extensions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have run bibtex . Please be patient with me if this is too trivial. When you say run bibtex, I just changed the dropdown list next to run button in TexWorks and click on the run button. After I do so, I would change the dropdown list back to pdfLatex then click on the run button again.

Comment: Then there must be a .blg-file somewhere. Find it. Don't let windows tell you that it is something else (e.g. a Performance Monitor file). Don't open it with double click but with the file menu of texworks.

Comment: See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). If you have run BibTeX there must be a `.blg` file (on Windows it might be classified as 'performance monitor file', but it is really just a text file you can open with your favourite text editor).

Comment: Ah... i finally found it... I had to tweak folder options not to hide the file extensions.  here are the contents
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: elsarticle-template.aux
The style file: model5-names.bst
Database file #1: mybibfile.bib
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 6000 items from 3000.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
You've used 1 entry,
            3390 wiz_defined-function locations,
            694 strings with 5479 charact

Comment: this is incomplete file

Comment: @moewe and Ulrike Fischer Thanks a lot for a quick support. The link moewe posted has a detailed explanation what could go wrong. I followed the steps and now it is working fine. I really love how the community supports newbies like me

Comment: please let me know.. how can i mark your comments as answers... :)

Comment: Since the other question solved your problem, I think the best course of action is to vote to close your question as duplicate.